# computerChoice variable not updating from Math.random

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a rock paper scissors game that will print to console. I am using a random number generator to set the computers choice but for some reason its not updating the variable. The random number is working but its always saying the computer is selecting rock even though the corresponding number is different.

```
console.log("Welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors!")
let userSelection = prompt("Please type \"r\" for rock, \"p\" for paper, or \"s\" for scissors.")

if (userSelection !== "r" && userSelection !== "p" && userSelection !== "s") {
    while (userSelection !== "r" && userSelection !== "p" && userSelection !== "s") {
        alert("Invalid input")
        userSelection = prompt("Please type \"r\" for rock, \"p\" for paper, or \"s\" for scissors")
    }
}

let computerChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1
console.log(computerChoice)
let rock = "Rock"
let paper = "Paper"
let scissors = "Scissors"

if (computerChoice = 1) {
    computerChoice = rock
} else if (computerChoice = 2) {
    computerChoice = paper
} else {
    computerChoice = scissors
}

if (userSelection === "r") {
    userSelection = rock
} else if (userSelection === "p") {
    userSelection = paper
} else {
    userSelection = scissors
}
```

I'm very new to this but it was working then all of a sudden stopped. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `if (computerChoice = 1)` should use `==`. `=` is assignment, `==` is comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your logic with this piece of code.

```js
if (computerChoice === 1) {
    computerChoice = rock
} else if (computerChoice === 2) {
    computerChoice = paper
} else {
    computerChoice = scissors
}
```

To elaborate on Barmars comment.

- =   is for value assignment
- ==  is for value comparison
- === is for value and type comparison